# Content is the same in both ul classes

Tags: html

I'm having a small issue here:

```
<div id="navbar">
<ul id="navtabs" class="floatcontainer">


        <li <?php if ($_GET['dept'] == "home") {echo"class='selected'";} ?>><a class="navtab" href="index3.php?dept=home">Home</a>

            <ul class="floatcontainer">

                <li><a href="?app=usercp">User Panel</a></li>
                <li><a href="?app=bugs">Report Bugs</a></li>
                <li><a href="?t=forum&app=index">Staff Forums</a></li>                  
            </ul>

        </li>   
        <li <?php if ($_GET['dept'] == "management") {echo "class='selected'";} ?>><a class="navtab" href="index3.php?dept=management">Management</a>

            <ul class="floatcontainer">
                <li><a href="?app=listuser">User Listing</a></li>                                   
            </ul>

        </li>
</ul>
```

In the code, the correct floatcontainer is meant to show up in each case for the li above, however, the bottom one, the floatcontainer with the User listing li only shows in both cases.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking? What do you mean with the correct floatcontainer is meant to... and what do you mean with the User listing li only shows in both cases? Is you question about a HTML/CSS issue or about the logic of your PHP if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the ul showing up unless $_GET['dept'] is some particular value, then put it inside an if() block?